# Can a Ruby module define class methods, so they also work when the module is nested?

Tags: ruby, module, class-method

Consider the following Ruby example of a class that includes a module which defines a class and instance method, and a second class that inherits the first.

```
 module Z
  def self.included(base)
    class << base
      def classmethod
        puts "Hello, I'm #{__method__} in #{self}"
      end 
    end 
  end 
  def instancemethod
    puts "Hello, I'm #{__method__} in #{self}"
  end 
end 

class A
  include Z
end 

class B < A 
end 

A.classmethod
A.new.instancemethod
B.classmethod
B.new.instancemethod
```

The output is as expected: both classes and instances have the methods defined by the module.

```
Hello, I'm classmethod in A
Hello, I'm instancemethod in #<A:0x85f4c10>
Hello, I'm classmethod in B
Hello, I'm instancemethod in #<B:0x85f4968>
```

Now, consider the scenario where the above module is included in another module which classes include instead:

```
module Y
  include Z
end

class C
  include Y
end

class D < C
end

Y.classmethod 
C.classmethod
C.new.instancemethod
D.classmethod
D.new.instancemethod
```

The instance methods work but the class methods on `C` and `D` don't (the `classmethod` is instead defined, where it isn't wanted, on the intermedate module `Y`).

**Can the module `Z` be modifed so that class methods are added to the class `C` rather than the intermediate module, `Y` ?**

The original scenario (i.e. where the module isn't nested) should also continue to work as above.

Comment: Calling `include` on a `module` that just happens to have previously included something doesn't mean you get the `include` dependency to chain over. Including a module in a module doesn't do quite what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: Would you accept an answer that involves doing something else than `include Z`?

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Concern` can help you here (both Z and Y would have to extend it). Is that an option for you?

Comment: I thought concern may be a way to approach it but I wondered if there was a ruby way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
module Y
  def self.included(base)
    Z.included(base)
  end
end

class C
  include Y
end

class D < C
end

Y.classmethod 
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `classmethod' for Y:Module

C.classmethod
  #=> Hello, I'm classmethod in C

C.new.instancemethod
  #=>Hello, I'm instancemethod in #<C:0x007ff58403d370>

D.classmethod
  #=> Hello, I'm classmethod in D

D.new.instancemethod     
  #=> Hello, I'm instancemethod in #<D:0x007ff5842478f0>
```

Four out of five is not bad, eh? I've run out of time now, but will see if I can get `Y.classmethod` to work. Perhaps a reader may have a suggestion.

Comment: That's great. `Y.classmethod` isn't needed. I'll test this out tomorrow. I was doing something like this but I must have done something wrong. It does require that `Y` is modified but I doubt that can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

@cary-swoveland's idea led me to try this, which solves the original problem: it is a modification to `Z` that works when it is nested:

```
module Z
  def self.included(base)
    class << base
      def classmethod
        puts "Hello, I'm #{__method__} in #{self}"
      end
      def included(base)
        Z.included(base)
      end
    end
  end
  def instancemethod
    puts "Hello, I'm #{__method__} in #{self}"
  end
end
```